# phpinfo and php -v show different version on mountain lion

Tags: php

I am trying to upgrade my php from 5.3.15 to 5.4.8 on Mac OSX 10.8.2.   I've manually downloaded the source code of php 5.4.8 and executed:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

I also added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to my `/etc/profile` file.

After that, `php -v` shows 5.4.8, while `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` still shows 5.3.15.

Any ideas on how to get `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to point to the newly installed php version?

Comment: what's the location of your php.ini in your phpinfo()?

Comment: This question should be moved to superuser.

Comment: Loaded Configuration File = /private/etc/php.ini

Answer (score 2):

That is happening to you because you have two version of php installed in your Mac, one with a  Web Server as an extension and the other one(the one from cli) is the one installed by default in your OS.

I installed php and apache  through mac ports. This will solve this problem to you. 
Try it!

Comment: This is correct. When you type `php -v` on the command line, that's your php-cli install.

Comment: I installed Mac Ports, any details on exactly how to install php from Mac Ports (i.e. steps).  I am looking at the documentation, but it's blah blah blah.

Comment: Read this http://blog.magudia.com/2009/08/22/installing-php53-apache2-mysql5-using-macports/